# How to use SCSS Theme into ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I downloaded a theme from ionic market. It is a paid theme. I want to use it in my ionic app.

How do I include the scss file into my app?

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply use the command `ionic setup sass` to setup Ionic to use SASS. So write the command in the terminal and Ionic does the setup automatically. You should do this at the start of the project. If you already have some CSS files you should back them up for safety.

When you run the command `ionic setup sass` Ionic will add a folder named `scss` and inside it there will be `ionic.app.scss` file that you can write SASS in. This will also alter your index.html file to include the SASS files instead of CSS files.

Here's also a video with instructions and details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_frPHsE2PZk

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the scss file(s) into the scss folder, at your project's root, then, open CLI, and use the command

```
gulp sass
```

You need to backup first your CSS files if you have edited them and want to keep it